# Ruby on rails: create action doesn't work, while new, edit and update (the same form as in create !) actions works - why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, methods

I have Realization model:

```
# encoding : utf-8
class Realization < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :city, :street, :title, :work, :photo, :date

  has_attached_file :photo
end
```

Controller:

```
# encoding : utf-8
class RealizationsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :admin_required, :except => [:index,:show]

  # GET /realization/new
  def new
    @realization = Realization.new
    @realization.date = Time.now.__send__(:to_date).to_s
  end

  # POST /realization
  def create
    @realization = Realization.new(params[:realization])

    if @realization.save
      redirect_to @realization, notice: 'realization was successfully created.'
    else
      render action: "new"
    end
  end

(...) others
```

View of form:

```
<%= form_for @realization, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
    <% if @realization.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@realization.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this realization from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
            <% @realization.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <li><%= msg %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :title %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :title %>
    </div>
    (...)
        <div class="field">
            <%= f.file_field :photo %>
        </div>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

And routes :

```
resources :realizations
```

And WEBrick server info is that:

```
Started POST "/realizacje" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-12 12:26:35 +0200
Processing by RealizationsController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"zK5jP4ChBBY+R21TjrZkp4xGvCHViTFJ+8Fw6Og28YY=", "realization"=>{"title"=>"wwwwww", "street"=>"", "city"=>"", "work"=>"", "date"=>"2013-04-12"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
   (1.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "realizations" 
  Realization Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "realizations".* FROM "realizations" ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 7 OFFSET 0
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Rendered realizations/index.html.erb within layouts/application (156.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 340ms (Views: 333.0ms | ActiveRecord: 4.0ms)
```

While I use the form and push the submit it redirects/randers realizations/index without notice or errors even! 
I have completely no idea why? Especialy that it worked before... 
Maybe javascript added later on may be the reason?
Paperclip works well in update so it isn't it...

Comment: Are you certain that the create action has not actually created a new entry in your database?  That is what the create action is for.

Comment: Would it be this line `before_filter :admin_required, :except => [:index,:show]`. Can you tell us what is does and if your signed in?

Comment: @derek_duncan: I pretty sure it hasn't create a new entry in DB -> also look and new added WEBrick info.

Comment: @Mab879: before filter :admin required is an autentication if user is an admin (only admin can add changes, but it works properly in other parts of website)

Answer (score 2):

You might check your new action to see what you're passing in to the form_for.

You want to be passing in a brand new instance of your Realization model.

i.e. in the new action you should have a line that reads @realization = Realization.new

The reason I suggest this is because form_for calls a method (#new_record?) on the object you give it and will submit a post or put request depending on whether that method call returns true or false.

Comment: But I'm using '@realization = Realization.new'
the line later: '@realization.date = Time.now.__send__(:to_date).to_s'
seems not to have any impact (I tried with and without it).

Even the button submit is automaticly named "Create realization", but it redirects to realization/index  - WHY?

Comment: As long as you don't save the new record in your controller i shouldn't be a problem.. it does sound like your form_for thinks the record is an existing one, so it submits a PUT instead of a POST. If your form is submitting a PUT request, it makes sense that your app is redirecting to your index page.

Comment: actualy in the site source I can see that:
'<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/realizacje" class="new_realization" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="new_realization" method="post">' so it thas think that it is POST, yet it doesn't create anything! Leaving only 
'def new'
  '@realization = Realization.new'
'end'
doesn't change that.